# Assert Types .NET

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mstest, assert

Is there a way that you can assert whether or not a variable is of a certain type?

Such as:

```
AssertIsBoolean(variable);
```

Comment: A variable is of the type it was declared as, look back a few lines in your source code.  If you see "object", only then start considering the offered answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you really trying to assert that a *variable* is of a particular type, or that the *value* of a variable is of a particular type?

The first shouldn't be part of a unit test - it's part of the declared code. It's like trying to unit test that you can't call a method with the wrong argument types.

The second can easily be accomplished with

```
Assert.IsTrue(value is bool);
```

(Assuming `value` is a variable of type `object` or an interface.)

Note that that will test for *compatibility* rather than the exact type. If you want to test that a value is an exact type, not a subtype, you might use something like:

```
Assert.AreEqual(typeof(ArgumentException), ex.GetType());
```

(There may be options available for generic methods in whatever unit test framework you use, of course.)

Comment: I think you mean `ex.GetType()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(myValue is Boolean)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Assert.IsTrue(variable is bool, "variable was not a Boolean Value");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which testing framework you use. So I would like to mention that the [**Gallio/MbUnit**](http://gallio.org) testing framework provides a convenient assertion for that very purpose:

```
Assert.IsInstanceOfType<bool>(myValue);
```

- [API documentation.](http://gallio.org/api/html/Overload_MbUnit_Framework_Assert_IsNotInstanceOfType.htm)